# Setting Position of View in API Level 7 Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-compatibility

At the moment I am trying to set the position of my programmatically created view using the following code:

```
LayoutParams params = bottomBar.getLayoutParams();
params.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,(float) 5, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
bottomBar.setLayoutParams(params);
bottomBar.setLeft(0);
bottomBar.setTop(this.getHeight()-bottomBar.getHeight());
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The error I get is that I cant use the `setLeft` and `setTop` properties in api levels less than 11.

**THE QUESTION**

How do I programmatically set the position of the view in `API level < 11`

Comment: The problem needs to do be outlined better, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe a simple layout diagram would help. If you want to align something to the bottom of the screen, think about relative layout using the equivalent of alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: check out [this answer][1] , it straight forward


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195768/android-use-of-view-setx-and-sety-in-api-8/28151869#28151869

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're already creating a custom view, so you would override `onLayout()` and call `View#layout(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` on the layout you want.

```
final int left = 0;
final int top = getHeight() - bottomBar.getHeight();
final int right = left + bottomBar.getWidth();
final int bottom = top + bottomBar.getHeight();
bottomBar.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
```